# App crashes before opening on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, crash

I have an app which works perfectly on the simulators. This app also worked perfectly on an iPhone* for a couple of months. After a few weeks of this app not being opened, the app crashes when I attempt to open it. It looks like its about to open but it quits.

If I double tap the Home button to display my cached apps I can see it there amongst the other cached apps and it looks fine, displaying on-screen elements and images(which are saved and retrieved from the filesystem) correctly. If I tap it, it again quits before running.

I was hoping to release this app asap as it is finished. I've searched the net for solutions but have not found any. I don't know what particular information may be needed to figure out the problem but please ask and I'll respond with it. I am relatively new to ios development.

*iPhone 5s running latest ios9 update

Comment: Check the device console log in Devices.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: @Avi  This only happens on the iPhone, not running in Xcode. Will the Device Console Log give me a log of the iPhone if I connect the iPhone to my laptop? I haven't used it before sorry

Comment: @Arc676  It's version 7.2.1

Comment: Should I be using some kind of 'crash log' to look into this?

Comment: What's happen if you run from xcode to that device ?

Comment: Yes, Xcode will show the device's console log.  It has nothing to do with running the app under the debugger.

Comment: @Avi  I have looked at the device log on the iPhone but I can't see this apps name in the log?  I've also looked at the Xcode's  windows > devices log but again couldn't see the app in there either? I haven't a clue what the results in the crash log console mean and the Processes column is empty

Comment: @Lion  I will run from Xcode to the device once I know a bit about why this might be happening because I figure that if I do and the app starts working/opening, upon release this may happen to the user because I didn't figure out why it happens hence not solving the problem.. if that makes sense?

Comment: If you run from xcode then only you come to know the error that why it is happening, thats why i have asked

Comment: Apple gives each app certain time to load. You must be performing some synchronus task in your `didLoad` or in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` . If your app takes more than alloted time the apple removes the app from launching queue. Check for any web API call which is taking time to load your UI.

Comment: Developer Apps have a short life. After a while, they can't run anymore. To "reset" that life expectancy, you have to run it through XCode, or TestFlight (which currently gives a lifetime of 60 days). For instance, with now "Free test" without paid account, it's like 24h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of Xcode is 7.3. You need to update your Xcode to the latest version to be able to upload to the latest version of iOS.

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention this earlier. The latest version of Xcode requires El Capitan (OS X 10.11).

**EDIT 2**: OP has now revealed that a provisioning profile is being used. These only last about a month. After they expire, the app is no longer trusted and will show the described behavior. This can only be solved by re-signing the code, which requires either a new provisioning profile or a Developer ID. In any case, after the code is re-signed, it has to be reinstalled, and installing onto the latest iOS requires the latest Xcode.

[image: About Xcode (7.3)]
[image: App Store: Xcode compatibility]

Sources coming soon.
OK, so I seem to be having some trouble finding the site where I found this information in the first place...

However, from the App Store:

> Xcode 7.3.1 includes [...] SDKs for iOS 9.3 [...].

Comment: No, this is not the proper solution. I am using xcode 7.2 and i normally runs my projects on ios 9.2 on my iPad.

Comment: @Lion OP said he is "running latest ios9 update". The latest version of iOS is 9.3.2.

Comment: Ohh sorry for that then i misunderstood that. I understand that it is running ios 9....!!

Comment: @DannyHuseyin : yeah then this answer seems right, you should update your xcode!

Comment: But why would the OS version on either the device or laptop cause the deployed app to not open 2 months after working perfectly and after not being opened for a few weeks?

Comment: Do you already have Developer ID? Or were you using a provisioning profile? Provisioning profiles only last a month or so.

Comment: @Arc676 A Provisioning Profile yes. Ok I didn't know that.. would that cause the kind of the problem I mentioned? I am a week away from having a Developer ID

Comment: Yes. I have had the exact same issue. See my edit for more info.

Comment: Provisioning profiles do **NOT** last only one month! They last up to one year.

Comment: @Kerni Really? Mine didn't last that long

Comment: @Kerni I just checked my current provisioning profiles. I don't remember exactly when I created them, but it was definitely this year (no earlier than April) and they expire in July.

Comment: I just created a distribution and an Ad-Hoc provisioning profile and it is valid for 1 year.

Comment: @Kerni Do you have a Developer ID? Perhaps that is what makes it different, as neither I nor the OP are currently in possession of one.